# Redirect with HttpResponseRedirect to another function in python

Tags: python, exception, redirect, httpresponse, reverse

I have a function :

```
def drawback(request,problem_id)
```

and I want in the end of this function to redirect to another page that is called from function

```
def show(request,problem_id)
```

I tried with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show',kwargs={'problem_id':10}))
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show',kwargs={'problem_id':'10'}))
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show',args=[10]))
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show',args=(10))
```

Everything I found in other sites. But I receive the error

```
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'show' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'problem_id': '10'}' not found.
```

or

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'show' with arguments '(u'10',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

This function and page works when I call it through html with a button. When I try to redirect from drawback function is not working.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import *
import settings
from django.conf import settings as rootsettings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # authentication
   (r'^start_auth', start_auth),
   (r'^after_auth', after_auth),

   # screens
   (r'^problems/codelookup$', code_lookup),

   # TESTING
   (r'^problems/test$', test_message_send),

   (r'^donnorsTool/$', problem_list),
   (r'^problems/delete/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)', archived_problem),
   (r'^problems/edit/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)', edit_problem),

   (r'^problems/restore/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)', restore_problem),
   (r'^problems/new$', new_problem),
   (r'^problems/archived$', archived_problems),
   (r'^donnorsTool/show/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)', show),
   (r'^donnorsTool/consent/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)/(?P<counter>[^/]+)', consent),
   (r'^donnorsTool/withdraw/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)/(?P<counter>[^/]+)', withdraw),

    # static
    ## WARNING NOT FOR PRODUCTION
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': rootsettings.SERVER_ROOT_DIR + settings.STATIC_HOME}),
)
```

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`

Comment: I posted in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like a function :

```
def drawback(request,problem_id) 
    ...
    ...
    return show(request,10)
```

Comment: I have tried this before and is not working. It is like the link is not changing the url in browser still writes .donnorsTool/withdraw/10/1

Comment: well, it won't change the browser url, it redirects the content that is sent to the user (server side), the url that appears in the browser is the url that was request by the user (client side). It is very useful to redirect the user to login / access denied / 404 pages, because it will change the page content, the url that was requested by the user is (somewhat) irrelevant, since you already did what you had to do on your view (in this case _drawback_).

Comment: if you really need to force a client request to your _show_ then I suggest you to use some JS on the _drawback_ response page

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/), you can do several things.

```
# using the Python path
reverse('news.views.archive')

# using the named URL
reverse('news_archive')

# passing a callable object
from news import views
reverse(views.archive)
```

I prefer names in case you want to change out the name of the view easily, so

in *urls.py*

```
(r'^donnorsTool/show/(?P<problem_id>[^/]+)', show, name='show'),
```

in *views.py*

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show',kwargs={'problem_id':10}))
```

Comment: I tried this but still the url in browser is donnorsTool/withdraw/10/1 shouldn't it say show/10 if it would have been redirected?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I am not sure if it is the best but for me it worked like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('../../show/'+problem_id)
```

I don't know if it will cause any problems like that.